# Draw axis icon in Scenekit

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, scenekit

I'm trying to draw a small icon at the corner of a viewport subclassed from `SCNView`, like the one present in most CAD programs:

[image: axis icon]

I have considered two options:

1. Use SceneKit, and come up with some sort of transformation using nested `SCNNode`s to keep the icon fixed in the corner.
2. Use OpenGL, and something like [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/165898-Draw-XYZ-axis-in-corner) to achieve the desired effect.

The first option seems feasible, but I cannot wrap my head around the proper transformations needed.

The second option is closer to what I have already tried in another, OpenGL-based app, but due to my limited experience in SceneKit, I cannot figure out how to mix OpenGL and SceneKit rendering. The only possibility seems to be the `-renderNode:renderer:arguments:` method of the `SCNNodeRendererDelegate` protocol, which seems kind of an overkill in my case, since, if I use it, I have to practically do all the rendering myself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would do this using pure OpenGL code. In the `-renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:` callback just draw your 3 axes in view space so that they always are at the same location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, works perfectly using OpenGL. I cannot understand how I missed that delegate method! If you would like, post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done using pure OpenGL code.

In the `-renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:` callback just draw your 3 axes in view space so that they always are at the same location.